# Get MAX Value IN SQL After SUM

Tags: mysql

I am having a table in SQL which is containing 2 points for 1 student_id in one match like in below Photo[image]

Now Like this there are many **Student_profile_ID** and **Basketball_Match_ID**. And I want to make the Student_profile_ID same and then add the points after That want to Get Who Score the Maximum point among them.

I am Able to Sum then But NOt able to GET the MAX value

```
SELECT student_profile_id,
       sum(point) as total_point 
from `basketball_points` 
where student_profile_id = {$value2} 
  AND basketball_match_id = {$key3}
```

Where Foreach Loop help me to increment the Value In PHP. And check all the results

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you tell us the result you expect ?

Comment: I think you just want `group by`.

Comment: To me isnt clear why you save multiple score for same player in same basketball match, looks like a db design error to me. Also isnt clear what is the maximum among them. You mean the max single score of one player `{$value2} ` the max sum of one player, the max sum amongst all player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `group by` along with `order by` and `limit`.  Here is the idea:

```
select student_profile_id, sum(point) as total_point
from `basketball_points`
where basketball_match_id = {$key3}
group by student_profile_id
order by total_point desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  this will only give you one student if multiple students are tied for the maximum.  Also, it is unclear whether or not you want the `where` clause.

If you want the total points for all students, leave out the `limit` clause.

Comment: Well Thank You So Much I will Appricate You Answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
SELECT 
    student_profile_id, 
    max(point) as max_point,
    sum(point) as total_points
FROM
    `basketball_points` 
WHERE student_profile_id = {$value2} AND basketball_match_id = {$key3}
```